# How to substitute "?" in a character vector in R?

Tags: r, string

How can I specify "?" as "ő" in a character vector? (ő is a Hungarian special character)
My original vector is:

```
 [1] "Mez?zombor.dbf"      "Szegi.dbf"           "Szegilong.dbf"       "Szerencs.dbf"       
 [5] "Tarcal.dbf"          "Tiszaladány.dbf"     "Tokaj.dbf"           "Bodrogkeresztúr.dbf"
 [9] "Bodrogkisfalud.dbf"  "Alsóberecki.dbf"     "Bodrogolaszi.dbf"    "Olaszliszka.dbf"    
[13] "Sárazsadány.dbf"     "Sárospatak.dbf"      "Sátoraljaújhely.dbf" "Vajdácska.dbf"      
[17] "Viss.dbf"            "Vámosújfalu.dbf"     "Zalkod.dbf"          "Fels?berecki.dbf"
```

I want "Mez?zombor.dbf" shown as "Mezőzombor.dbf".
I've tried `gsub` as:

```
HHH = gsub("?", "ő", HHH) ## HHH is the vectors name
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape `?`, which is a regex metacharacter, meaning many things, among them optionality (as in `x?`, which matches `x`optionally), 'laziness' as in `.*?`, which makes the match lazy in the sense that it stops at the first possible match), and to start lookarounds (as in `(?<=...)`, which is a positive lookbehind asserting a condition to the left of the actual match):

```
 gsub("\\?", "ő", x)
```